# SEO friendly url in Yii

Tags: php, yii, clean-urls, yii-url-manager

I need a rule for http://example.com/post/view/id/1 url that will be displayed like this http://example.com/post/post_title. 
Instead of the id number i want to display the post name or title.

My config looks like this:

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(             
            //'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            //'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            //'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have a rule that looks like this

```
'post/<post_title:\w+>'=>'postController/view/title/<post_title>',
```

This just tells the app to forward requests that start with a post/post_title  to the post controller's actionView where $_GET['title'] is set to post_title...

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple rule

```
'post/<post_title:\w+>' => 'post/view'
```

If need  url like this http://example.com/post/some-title-with-hyphen

```
'post/<post_title:[-\w]+>' => 'post/view'
```

And you need a controller action with $post_title argument

```
public function actionView($post_title) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

in default, Yii only retreive the post id, if you want to display the post title, you need to access the DB your self in a custom Url class rules. there is an example in the yii tutorial called [using-custom-url-rule-classes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes)